# How to make global variable for inputs and why addition

Tags: javascript

```js
function additon() {
 const value_1 = document.getElementById('value_1').value;
 const value_2 = document.getElementById('value_2').value;
 const answer = document.getElementById('answer');
 
 var additon = (value_1 + value_2);
 
 answer.innerHTML = additon;
}
function subtraction(){
 const value_1 = document.getElementById('value_1').value;
 const value_2 = document.getElementById('value_2').value;
 const answer = document.getElementById('answer');

 var subtraction = (value_1 - value_2);

 answer.innerHTML = subtraction;
}
```

```html
Enter value 1 <input type="tel" id="value_1">
<br>
Enter value 2 <input type="tel" id="value_2">
<br>

Answer: <span class="answer" id="answer"></span> 
<br>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="additon()">+</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" onclick="subtraction()">-</button>
<button class="btn btn-succes btn-lg" onclick="multiplication()">X</button>
<button class="btn btn-succes btn-lg" onclick="division()">/</button>
```

Why addition `1 + 1 = 11`. Subtraction working correct and how to make global variable for the value inputs I want to be a this calculator for real time update.

Comment: It handles as a string instead of a number, it concats those. You need convert the values into numbers.

Comment: Use parseInt like ```const value_1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('value_1').value);```

Answer (score 1):

```
function additon() {
    const value_1 = document.getElementById('value_1').value;
    const value_2 = document.getElementById('value_2').value;
    const answer = document.getElementById('answer');

    var additon = (value_1*1 + value_2*1); // Multiplying changes the type to NUM

    answer.innerHTML = additon;
}
function subtraction(){
    const value_1 = document.getElementById('value_1').value;
    const value_2 = document.getElementById('value_2').value;
    const answer = document.getElementById('answer');

    var subtraction = (value_1*1 - value_2*1); // Multiplying changes the type to NUM

    answer.innerHTML = subtraction;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is taking it as `string` rather than `integer`. try this:

```js
function additon() {
 var value_1 = document.getElementById('value_1').value;
 var value_2 = document.getElementById('value_2').value;
 var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
 
 var additon = +value_1 + +value_2;
 
 answer.innerHTML = additon;
}
```

```html
Enter value 1 <input type="tel" id="value_1">
<br>
Enter value 2 <input type="tel" id="value_2">
<br>

Answer: <span class="answer" id="answer"></span> 
<br>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="additon()">+</button>
```

**OR**

you can use [Number()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp) will take care of numbers.

```js
function additon() {
 var value_1 = Number(document.getElementById('value_1').value);
 var value_2 = Number(document.getElementById('value_2').value);
 var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
  
 var addition = value_1 + value_2; 

 
 answer.innerHTML = addition;
}
```

```html
Enter value 1 <input type="tel" id="value_1">
<br>
Enter value 2 <input type="tel" id="value_2">
<br>

Answer: <span class="answer" id="answer"></span> 
<br>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="additon()">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The values are handled as string type which are coming from the `input` elements. You need to convert them into numbers. You can use [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) constructor for that purpose.

This is a simulation what happened in your case:

```js
const value_1 = '1';
const value_2 = '1';     
const addition = value_1 + value_2;
 
console.log(addition);
```

Please find a possible resolution for your case:

```js
const value_1 = '1';
const value_2 = '1';
let addition;

if (!isNaN(value_1) && !isNaN(value_2)) {
   addition = Number(value_1) + Number(value_2);
}
 
console.log(addition);
```

I hope this helps!